# Domain DNS server and DNS IP record

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting

I'm sorry for the weird question title, but I don't know how to describe the problem in just a few words. I accept suggestions for new title.

Here is my issue, or actually I am not experienced enough in server administration to understand/solve it myself.

I have a server at `IP X`
I have a domain `mydomain.com` purchased from a hosting company
I want to create DNS server `ns1.mydomain.com` 
I want mydomain.com to use `ns1.mydomain.com` DNS server

How I can set `ns1.mydomain.com` to use `IP X` and it's DNS server to serve DNS requests when I cannot set IP as DNS record for `ns1.mydomain.com` in the hosting company control panel.
Should I first use my hosting company's DNS hosting insert A record for `mydomain.com` to point to `IP X` and then setup subdomain (I guess) `ns1.mydomain.com` where I can place my DNS server.

Illustration of the scheme:

Domain `mydomain.com` using NS `ns1.mydomain.com` points to `IP X`
But how to set `ns1.mydomain.com` to point to `IP X`

**Edit:**

### The answer

Quote from [Alnitak](https://serverfault.com/a/135758/168479):

You only need glue records when the hostname for your nameserver is part of the same domain as it's trying to serve.

Glue records are published in the parent zone. Hence if the operator of example.com wanted to have nameservers named ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com then the .com domain would need something like:

```
example.com.     IN NS ns1.example.com.
                 IN NS ns2.example.com.
ns1.example.com. IN A  192.0.2.1
ns2.example.com. IN A  198.51.100.5
```

(example subnets taken from RFC 5737).

The child zone would usually have the same A records in it (even if only for consistency), but when they're in the child zone they're not technically glue records any more.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. Please post answers in the Answer section below. Otherwise they may be missed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've needed to do such a thing I've always needed to contact my domain host to do this, although Xilo have added the functionality to set your own NS server IP's in the control panel, so yours may have this if they're good!

Comment: I think I've found to solution. The record I need is Glue record (or Child Name server).